# Problem with adding a sum for a cumulative chart

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to make a script that plots the difference in gaps on a cumulative basis. But it doesn't return any data.

I've tried declaring the variables for the sum inside the if statement using := . The sum works but as soon as the sum is added to a float to make it cumulative the data disappears.

Any ideas?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=false)

Xopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Xclose = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Xsum = Xopen-Xclose[1]

var float Xzero = 0
var float Yzero = 0

//var float Xsum = 5

if barstate.isnew
    Xzero := Yzero+Xsum
    Yzero := Xzero
    
plot(Xzero)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Xsum = Xopen-Xclose[1]
```

On the very first bar, there is no historical data, so `Xclose[1]` will return `NaN`.
Any calculation with a `NaN` will also result in `NaN`.
Therefore, all your variables will be `NaN`.

You should replace the `NaN` value with `0` by using the [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_nz) function, like this:

```
Xsum = Xopen-nz(Xclose[1])
```

This will work:

```
//@version=4 
study("My Script", overlay=false)

Xopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Xclose = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
Xsum = Xopen - nz(Xclose[1])

var float Xzero = 0
var float Yzero = 0

if barstate.isnew
    Xzero := Yzero+Xsum
    Yzero := Xzero

plot(Xzero)
```